# How to extract text/string out of MySQL SELECT Query Result with PHP QueryPath without getting "extra HTML" that I am getting?

Tags: php, mysql, querypath

I created a small test database which looks like this:

```
mysql> select * from person;
+-----------+-------------+
| firstName | lastName    |
+-----------+-------------+
| matt      | butcher     |
| emanuel   | garbaciovas |
+-----------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And then I wrote a simple QueryPath Script Like this:

```
<?php

    require 'src/QueryPath/QueryPath.php';
    require 'src/QueryPath/Extension/QPDB.php';



    $input = qp(QueryPath::XHTML_STUB,'body')
      ->dbInit('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=qpdb',
        array(username=>'my_username',password=>'my_password'))
      ->queryInto('SELECT firstName FROM person WHERE lastName="butcher"')
      ->doneWithQuery()->writeHTML()->find('body')->text();

    print $input;

?>
```

Now, I need a string[text value] of the query which I get [i.e. I get what I want, which then I use as an input into html text form on the web/excel/csv/etc], but the problem is, when I run this script from command line, I get extra block of HTML code/document generated which I dont need, i.e. output looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/x
html1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta>
  <title>Untitled</title>
  </head>
  <body>matt</body>
  </html>
matt
```

So basically what I want is "matt", which is what I get, but I also get all of this "extra" as you can see which I dont want. Does anyone know how to extract only "matt"?

I obviously I cant extract text straight out of MySQL query, because it is a resource/object so does anyone knows a way/hack around it? QueryPath or No QueryPath is fine [althought QueryPath hack is better!]

Comment: why using querypath if you don't want html?

Comment: try remove `writeHTML()`

Comment: when I remove writeHTML() I get: uncaught exception: cant convert class of QueryPath Object to string...